# How to make user's input only certain numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got an input, how can i make that the user only can write numbers from 1 to 31?

```
<input maxlength="2">
```

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="number" min="1" max="31">`?  Are you ever going to allow ***any other symbol*** other than a number?

Comment: `<input type="number" min="1" max="31">`?

Comment: but my maxlength doesn't work

Comment: 1 to 31 feels like dealing with a _date_. If that's so you could use `<input type="date">` or wire up a 3rd party datepicker... because the real max would be 31, or 30, or 29, or 28

Comment: "my maxlength doesn't work" — saying only "doesn't work" does not give anybody enough information to help. _How_ does it not work? What do you expect should happen? What is actually happening? See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75073835/how-can-i-fix-my-input-value-into-december-2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="31">
```