# How can i fix my input value into december 2022?

Tags: html, css

In my project, I need to make a default month and year which the user can't change. He should change only the date in December months. How can I do it?

```
<input id="input_date" type="date" maxlength="2" min="1" max="31">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min` and `max` should be dates, not numbers. `maxlength="2"` is not appropriate, since dates have 10 characters.

```html
<input id="input_date" type="date" min="2022-12-01" max="2022-12-31">
```

Or you could use `type="number"` if you just want the day of the month.

```html
<input id="input_date" type="number" maxlength="2" min="1" max="31">
```